# How do I edit this collider to fit my spike sprite size exactly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, collider

[image: Weird collider]

Hello, I am using tilemap collider and composite collider on my spike tilemap object. Used by composite is checked on my tilemap collider. These colliders are all 2D. How do I edit this collider to fit exactly to the spike sprite image?

I tried editing the values on both of the colliders but I couldn't find a viable solution.

Comment: Can you make sure there really isn't any color information on those pixels around the line ? Usually the collider gets cut where there is really a complete transparent area

Comment: Yes, it is completely transparent when I edit it on Aseprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the collider shapes in the sprite editor using [Custom Physics Shape](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPhysicsShape.html)

Comment: To my understanding the shape can be made freehand. You use generate to get an approximation first, then you manually edit the control points and add/remove points to fit your shape. In what way did it not work?